# JDialog is not visible

Tags: java, swing, awt, visibility, jdialog

I have a problem with a custom `JDialog`, that is created in its own thread by the main frame.

Sometimes the `JDialog` is invisible, but its controlls are clickable (if you know where their position is). The problem does not occur on Oracle Java 1.7, but definetly on Oracle Java 1.6 (seen in **1.6.0_37** and **1.6.0_45**).

I create the dialog like this:

```
class MyDialog extends Jdialog() {
 public MyDialog(JFrame frame, boolean modal) {
   super(frame, modal);
   [...]
  }
}
```

In my Mainframe:

```
MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(myMainFrame,true);
dialog.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

The expected behaviour is to block events like `MouseEvents` of the mainframe and lie over it. That works perfectly on Java 1.7.

So my question is, are there any special things to keep in mind when creating `JDialogs` like create it only, after the parentframe (owner) is visible or is it maybe a known bug of the used Java JRE? I already checked at the bug fix log of Oracle [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u37-relnotes-1863283.html) without success.

Comment: There should be no reason to call `repaint()` or `revalidate` as @subash suggests. Your problem sounds intermittent which to me smells of a Swing threading issue. Are you taking care to make all Swing calls on the EDT? And to call long-running code off of the EDT? Best were if you could post short code that compiles, runs, and reproduces your problem here, an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: You are right, an SSCCE would be better, but my problem is taking part in a large code project so an sccce would unfortunately not reproduce my problem. I think @Durandal hint leads me in the right direction, because it seems to be a problem with threading. That would explain, why it doesn't happen always but only sometimes. The JAVA 1.6 / 1.7 issue might be related to a different design. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I have a problem with a custom JDialog, *that is created in its own thread* by the main frame"

If thats literally true, that the problem.

You should not create instances of Swing objects, especially *JComponent* on any other thread than the Event Dispatch Thread. Swing is not entirely thread safe, use SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()/invokeLater() to execute GUI related code when you're not absolutely sure you're on the EDT.